# Merge duplicated cells in bulk per each column VBA

Tags: performance, vba

Need to merge data per column if records in the first column are the same.

I wrote a VBA code and it works but it works very slow as it executes "merge" function per each row no matter if consequent cells are the same or different.

```
Sub DuplicateValues()

'Declare All Variables:

Dim myCell As Range
Dim myRow As Integer
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Dim myFirstRow As Long
Dim myFirstColumn As Long

Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range

'Count Number of Rows and Columns:

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

myRow = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown)).Count + 2 'first two rows are headers
myCol = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight)).Count

'Apply formatting to the end of the table:

With ActiveSheet
Set rngCopy = .Range(.Range("A3"), .Cells(myRow, myCol))

 With rngCopy.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End With

'Merge duplicated cells per Row:

myFirstRow = 3
myFirstColumn = 1

Set iRow = Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn)
Set n = Cells(myFirstRow + 1, myFirstColumn)

For i = 1 To myRow

    If iRow <> n Then

                Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 8), Cells(myFirstRow, 8)).WrapText = True
                Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).EntireRow.AutoFit       

                iRow = Cells(myFirstRow + i, myFirstColumn)
                n = Cells(myFirstRow + i + 1, myFirstColumn)

                Else
                n = Cells(myFirstRow + i + 1, myFirstColumn)

                    For k = 1 To myCol - 3 'need to merge data per column but don't need to merge data in the last 3 columns

                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).Merge
                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, 8), Cells(myFirstRow + i, 8)).WrapText = True
                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).EntireRow.AutoFit

                    Next

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I  tried to create a different logic to initiate "merge" by blocks (skip merging the same value cells in the first column right away):
merging only when the "base/initial" cell is not the same as a "check" cell and merge all appropriate cells all together (not by each row), but I can't find a way to make it work.

Would be very grateful for any code optimizations!

Comment: Unrelated for performance, but avoid using `With`, it just obfuscates code and makes it less readable.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> 'Declare All Variables:
>
> Dim myCell As Range
> Dim myRow As Integer
> Dim myRange As Range
> Dim myCol As Integer
> Dim i As Integer
> Dim k As Integer
>
> Dim myFirstRow As Long
> Dim myFirstColumn As Long
>
> Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
> ```

Don't do this. This procedure is somewhere between 2 and 3 screens high on my laptop: when I'm at the bottom of the procedure, I don't know what I'm looking at, so I scroll back up to this *wall of declarations*, parse the chunk of code, locate the variable I'm looking for, then scroll back down to where I was, ...and that gets very annoying, very fast.

People defending this "declare everything at the top of the procedure" habit usually defend it pretty hard, and they're wrong. "I can see everything that's used in the procedure at once" sounds great on paper. Truth is, it only makes you scroll back and forth all the time for no reason, *and* makes it much harder than it should be, to know whether or not a variable is used, let alone *where* it's used.

If you declare variables where you first assign them, as you need to introduce them, then you simply *can't* miss the fact that `myCell`, `myRange`, `rngPaste` are never assigned or referenced anywhere... and that `iRow` and `n` aren't declared at all. This is extremely bug-prone, you don't want to allow VBA code to run with undeclared variables. Fortunately you can completely prevent this, by simply specifying `Option Explicit` at the very top of every module you ever write any VBA code in.

Proper indentation also helps, massively. It started well:

```
For i = 1 To myRow

    If iRow <> n Then
```

...and then suddenly went *way out there*:

```
                Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

...to seemingly random:

```
            Else
            n = Cells(myFirstRow + i + 1, myFirstColumn)

                For k = 1 To myCol - 3 'need to merge data per column but don't need to merge data in the last 3 columns
```

Use an [indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) if you're unsure how to keep indentation consistent.

Row numbers should always be `As Long`. An `Integer` is a 16-bit signed integer type, so its maximum possible value is 32,767. This means as soon as your data involves row 32,768 and beyond, your code breaks with an "Overflow" run-time error. In fact, there's little to no reason at all to ever declare anything `As Integer` in 2019: processors are optimized to deal with 32-bit integer types, and that's a `Long` in VBA.

I like this:

> ```
> With ActiveSheet
> ```

I makes `ActiveSheet` references explicit, and that's very good.

However you're *implicitly* referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is everywhere else outside this `With` block.

> ```
> myRow = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown)).Count + 2 'first two rows are headers
> myCol = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight)).Count
> ```

Unqualified like this, `Range` and `Cells` are implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`: the `With ActiveSheet` block is therefore redundant, and makes accesses to that active sheet inconsistent: some are explicit, some are implicit - and that's very bug-prone.

A note about this:

```
myRow = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown)).Count + 2 'first two rows are headers
```

Looks like you're trying to get the last used row; this is not a reliable way to do it. Consider flipping the logic around and going *up* from the last row on the sheet to get the `.Row` of that specific cell, rather than the `Count` of cells in a range:

```
myRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Note how the fist two rows being headers, doesn't matter any more.

I'd strongly advise *against* using `my` as a prefix for anything, regardless of how often you see it in documentation. Same goes for `rng` and `o` and whatever other prefixing scheme you might read anywhere. Use meaningful names instead. "myRow" doesn't say what's important about it: it's the last row with data. `lastRow` would already be a much better name for it.

`rngCopy` is assigned, its borders are formatted, ...but it's not being *copied* anywhere. The name strongly suggests it's a `source`, especially since it's declared right next to the unused `rngPaste`, which strongly suggests that would be a `destination` for an operation involving the clipboard. Pretty misleading, since none of that is happening anywhere in the procedure.

I already mentioned `n` isn't declared. Its usage is a problem.

```
Set n = Cells(myFirstRow + 1, myFirstColumn)
```

It's `Set`-assigned to a `Range`. Thus, its runtime type at that point is `Variant/Range`.

```
If iRow <> n Then
```

Now it's being compared to `iRow`, which is another undeclared `Variant/Range` variable, and the two objects are only comparable through implicit let-coercion involving hidden default member calls - making it all explicit would look like this:

```
If iRow.Value <> n.Value Then
```

And while that's now explicit, it's wrong. It's wrong, because they shouldn't be `Range` objects. They shouldn't be `Range` objects, because they're later being `Let`-assigned to plain values:

```
        iRow = Cells(myFirstRow + i, myFirstColumn)
        n = Cells(myFirstRow + i + 1, myFirstColumn)
```

Beyond that point, the data type of `iRow` and `n` is up in the air. If you're lucky, you're looking at two `Variant/Double` values. Otherwise, you're looking at one or more `Variant/Error` values (that would be the case if the worksheet contains error values), and everything blows up with a *type mismatch* error.

Not declaring variables is one thing, reusing variables is another, but reusing undeclared variables and assigning them a new runtime type, makes everything very hard to follow. Declare them with an explicit data type, and let them *be* values, instead of *objects that behave like values* thanks to implicit hidden code.

As for performance, the reason it's slow is because it's doing the single slowest thing any code can do: interact with worksheet cells directly, in a loop.

You can't help it, interacting with worksheet cells is *precisely* what this macro needs to do. All you *can* do is tell Excel to stop trying to keep up as you modify the worksheet.

Every time a cell is modified, Excel evaluates whether a recalc is needed, and will perform it if it has to. Switch calculation to manual before you start manipulating the worksheet, and toggle it back to automatic when you're done: Excel will only recalculate once. That's `Application.Calculation` (set to `xlCalculationManual`, then back to `xlCalculationAutomatic` when you're ready).

Every time a cell is modified, Excel fires worksheet events (e.g. `Worksheet.Change`), and if there's a handler procedure for that event, then that code will run before the next instruction does. Turn off application events before you start manipulating the worksheet, and toggle it back on when you're done: no worksheet events will be fired; that's `Application.EnableEvents` (set to `False`, then back to `True` when you're ready).

Every time a cell is modified, Excel tries to repaint itself. While that's normally pretty fast, when you're modifying cells in a loop you don't want Excel to even try to keep up - you want to make your changes, and have Excel repaint itself when you're done. Do that by toggling `Application.ScreenUpdating` (set to `False`, then back to `True` when you're ready).

Whenever you toggle this global `Application` state, make sure you handle runtime errors, and have your error-handling subroutine ensure that the global state gets properly reset whether the procedure succeeds or fails, whatever the reason for failing might be.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations on my errors, I just started writing codes on VBA and this is very helpful! Regarding performance, don't you think that if other logic was used, like merging only duplicated cells that are following each other (skipping merging every row) would increase the speed? I just don't know how to make it works that way...

Comment: It probably would, but I'm pretty sure the overhead of Excel recalculating and redrawing stuff *every time* dwarfs any algorithmic tweaks - best do *both* (turn off recalcs & repaints *and* review the algorithm)

Comment: Another question is about `myRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` that's a great way of getting the last row but I'm now getting an error: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Is `ws` defined? I only put it there to emphasize that `Range` is a member call that needs to be qualified with a proper `Worksheet` object.

Comment: Yes, I defined `ws`: `Dim ws As Worksheet`

Comment: And it's `Set`-assigned? ;-)

Comment: If I do it `Set`-assigned, I'm getting another error: Object required. Also, after I changed my code using your suggestions, it doesn't perform as it used to, maybe because I didn't assign `n` and `iRow` correctly (I assigned them `As Objects`)..

Comment: Not sure what state your code is in now... [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) should help you clean everything up (confession: I used it to clean up the indentation, identify unused variables, and other issues; full disclaimer: I manage this VBIDE add-in open-source project). `n` and `iRow` need to be `Long` integers, not objects,

Comment: I tried assigning `Long` before but I got the same error: Object required but now for the first row with `iRow`. I've already cleaned the indentation but overall can't really figure out why the code doesn't work anymore after just making a couple of alterations you suggested. I feel that in order to have the code aligned with the suggestions above I have to re-write/update lots of other things as well.

Comment: You'd get "Object Required" with a `Long` on the instructions where you're trying to `Set`-assign it. The changes I've suggested can't really be cherry-picked, it's all or none :)

Comment: Yep, that worked, thanks. I will try to figure out why I can't merge rows per column, something wrong with the loop `For k = 1 To myCol - 3` now

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to create a different logic to initiate "merge" by blocks (skip merging the same value cells in the first column right away):

The best way to do this is count the number of duplicates and then define your range as `current row to (current row - (number of duplicates + 1))` (note: you add 1 because the original value is not a duplicate).

> ```
> Range(Cells(i - (countDups + 1), k), Cells(i, k))
> ```

Hard coded values that may change in the future are called Magic Numbers.  Replacing these values with an enumeration or constants will make you code easier to read and modify.

For example the number 3 appears appears 4 times in code.  Each occurrence is being used to determine the number of columns to exclude.  If you later decide that you only need to exclude a 2 columns, you could just change all the 3's to 2.  No problem, ease pease.  So let's say we did that but decided to we did indeed need the to exclude the 3rd column, no problem just replace the 2's with 3's.  But wait there are 2 header rows, now there is a problem.

Before

> ```
> Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)
> ```

After

> ```
> Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - ColumnOffset)
> ```

Anything that is in going to happen `If` or `Else` does not belong in an `If` statement.

```
If iRow <> n Then

    Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 8), Cells(myFirstRow, 8)).WrapText = True
    Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).EntireRow.AutoFit

    iRow = Cells(myFirstRow + i, myFirstColumn)
    n = Cells(myFirstRow + i + 1, myFirstColumn)

Else
    n = Cells(myFirstRow + i + 1, myFirstColumn)

    For k = 1 To myCol - 3 'need to merge data per column but don't need to merge data in the last 3 columns

        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).Merge
        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, 8), Cells(myFirstRow + i, 8)).WrapText = True
        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).EntireRow.AutoFit

    Next

End If
```

The `k` loop is disguising the fact that the `HorizontalAlignment`, `VerticalAlignment` and row height are being adjusted whether `iRow <> n` or not.  Knowing this we can move these operations outside the scope of the `If` statement.  This will make it much easier to focus on the `if...Else` logic.

> ```
> If iRow <> n Then
>     iRow = Cells(myFirstRow + i, myFirstColumn)
> Else
>     For k = 1 To myCol - 3
>         Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).Merge
>     Next
> End If
>
> n = Cells(myFirstRow + i + 1, myFirstColumn)
> Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 8), Cells(myFirstRow, 8)).WrapText = True
> With Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3))
>     .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
>     .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
>     .EntireRow.AutoFit
> End With
> ```

If we think about it a little deeper, these formats are being applied to all cells in our target area.  The formatting isn't even essential to merging the cells, which is what we are really trying to do.  So we could simply pass the area to be formatted to another subroutine (see code below).   This will simplify the main code and make it much easier to focus on the task at hand.

### Refactored Code

```
Sub MergeDuplicateValues()
    Const DebugMode As Boolean = True

    Dim Target As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    If DebugMode Then
        Rem Close previous test workbook
        CloseTestWorkbooks
        Rem Copy the worksheet to a new workbook
        ws.Copy
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    End If

    Rem Define the Target Range
    Set Target = getMergeRange(ws.Range("A1"))
    Rem Add breakpoint here and use Target.Select in the Immediate Window to test the range

    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MergeDuplicates Target
    ApplyBorders Target.CurrentRegion
    ApplyFormatsToMergeArea Target

End Sub

Private Sub MergeDuplicates(Target As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim r As Long, countDups As Long

    With Target
        For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If .Cells(r, 1).Value = .Cells(r + 1, 1).Value Then
                countDups = countDups + 1
            Else
                If Count > 0 Then
                    Dim Column As Range

                    Rem Iterate over each column of the Target Range
                    For Each Column In .Columns
                        Dim section As Range
                        Set section = Column.Cells(r - countDups, 1).Resize(countDups + 1)

                        Rem Add breakpoint here and use section.Select in the Immediate Window to test the range
                        section.Merge
                    Next
                    Count = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Private Function getMergeRange(Target As Range) As Range
    Const LastColumnOffset As Long = -3
    Const FirstRowOffset As Long = 2

    Dim newTarget As Range
    With Target.CurrentRegion

        Rem An error handler is needed when setting a range using negative offsets
        On Error Resume Next

        Rem Define the actual Target range
        Set newTarget = .Offset(FirstRowOffset).Resize(.Rows.Count - FirstRowOffset, .Columns.Count + LastColumnOffset)

        Rem Add breakpoint here and use newTarget.Select in the Immediate Window to test the range

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 513, Description:="Unable to create Merged Range"
            Exit Function
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Set getMergeRange = newTarget
End Function

Private Sub ApplyBorders(Target As Range)
    With Target.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ApplyFormatsToMergeArea(Target As Range)
    Const NumberOfColumns As Long = 8

    With Target
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Resize(, NumberOfColumns).WrapText = True
        .Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CloseTestWorkbooks()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If Len(wb.Path) = 0 Then wb.Close 0
    Next
End Sub
```